Replace wpa_supplicant with own implementation
I've my own process for instance named as VikProcess which inherited with possible code of wps_supplicant (dport, systemd, events.c, scan.c etc..) in order to get essential code features of wps_supplicant.
Now, can someone please guide me to replace all possible services of wps_supplicant and use VikPropcess to communicate with Debian OS (RPI-3) NetworkManager services? Any lead would be helpful and appreciated.

you don't have to do anything, just call your fork the same and react to the same interfaces.

you don't have to do anything, just call your fork the same and react to the same interfaces.
That's your only option: you cannot possibly know all uses of some software and "fix" all other software.
